# Bootstrap full screen header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to get a full screen `background` in the `header` tag but for some reason it doesnt show?

**Code**

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing `height:100%` in `header` but even so it won't display because this a child of `body` and `html` you need to give `height:100%` and `width:100%` to parents (`body/html`)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(//placehold.it/500) center / cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Another approach is using `100vh`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(//placehold.it/500) center / cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: Is there a downside to using 100vh? I have been designing web pages for a while and somehow missed that simple solution.

Comment: Well recently (not sure since when) in chrome mobile the address bar counts for 100vh, so you will have to take that in consideration. I've been using 100vh myself too but most of the times due to this feature (let's call that) of chrome I've been calculating height with js